# How to save a file in nonblocking manner in R

Tags: r

How to save a large file in a nonblocking manner?

I am using JupyterLab with R to do data analysis. Sometimes I need to save a large object (for instance 15GB) with saveRDS function. This blocks the kernel and I have to wait until it finishes saving the file before running even a simple print statement.

I feel like this maybe possible using promises but I could not find a proper way to do it.

Comment: Use `future`s, see e.g. https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/future/vignettes/future-1-overview.html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I have come up with, please do improve it if possible.

```
library(future)
plan(multisession)

# read some data (dummy example)
data = readRDS('/path/to/some/data.rds')

# save the data
data_size = object.size(data)

path_to_save = "/path/to/save.rds"
size_of_path_object = object.size(path_to_save)

# adjust the limit on the total size of globals for exporting to future expressions
options(future.globals.maxSize = data_size + size_of_path_object) 
saved = future({
    saveRDS(data, path_to_save)
})

# restore original limit
original_limit = 500 * 1024^2
options(future.globals.maxSize = original_limit)
```

You can check if the file is save with this: `resolved(saved)`. Which will return either TRUE or FALSE.